# Hyperledger fabric v1: No system chain found while starting orderer peer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Trying to set up a basic testnet by following the document at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html
Using docker compose and the sample `docker-compose-no-tls.yaml` file.
Getting the following error with orderer:

```
orderer.example.com       | 2017-05-09 22:37:26.733 UTC [orderer/multichain] NewManagerImpl -> DEBU 102 Starting chain: 74657374636861696e6964
orderer.example.com       | 2017-05-09 22:37:26.733 UTC [orderer/ramledger] Iterator -> DEBU 103 Attempting to return block 0
orderer.example.com       | 2017-05-09 22:37:26.733 UTC [orderer/multichain] newChainSupport -> DEBU 104 Retrieved metadata for tip of chain (block #0): 
orderer.example.com       | 2017-05-09 22:37:26.733 UTC [orderer/multichain] NewManagerImpl -> CRIT 105 No system chain found
orderer.example.com       | panic: No system chain found
orderer.example.com       | 
orderer.example.com       | goroutine 1 [running]:
orderer.example.com       | panic(0xadb720, 0xc4203a8f30)
orderer.example.com       |   /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Panicf(0xc420185fb0, 0xbf561f, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/op/go-logging/logger.go:194 +0x127
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/multichain.NewManagerImpl(0x116bb60, 0xc42032c060, 0xc42028a660, 0x1169260, 0x11af8c0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/multichain/manager.go:125 +0x5c6
orderer.example.com       | main.main()
orderer.example.com       |   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:174 +0x1787
```

Can't figure out what's causing it. Any hint anyone?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I've run into the same thing today while trying to upgrade to alpha2. Unfortunately regenerating the artefacts as the answer below suggests, didn't help.

Comment: On second thoughts... if you haven't already fixed your issue, take a look at this: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3894

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use the wrong configtxgen.

I met the same problem and it has been solved by regenerate orderer.block using configtxgen from release.tar.gz.

configtxgen is still in develop, files generated by different version of configtxgen are quite different, and are not guaranteed to be compatible.